# Oracle BI: Select all records from last week

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence

I need to get all records with a date between Sunday and Saturday last week, inclusive, for whatever date the query is run.  For today, April 19th 2011, that would be from April 10th to April 16th.

When I entered the dates manually and converted the filter to SQL, I got the following syntax:

```
RESOLVED_DATE BETWEEN timestamp '2011-04-10 00:00:00' AND timestamp '2011-04-16 00:00:00'
```

I'm not even sure this is correct, because it seems to exclude dates on the 16th itself (shouldn't the time be 23:59:59?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to determine the dates you want using combinations of [next_day](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions098.htm) and regular date arithmetic. Below code should be pretty close, but it's untested and probably fails on some corner case, but at least you get the general idea :)

```
where resolved_date >= next_day( trunc(sysdate) - interval '14' day, 'SUN')
  and resolved_date <  next_day( trunc(sysdate) - interval '7'  day, 'SUN')
```

`trunc(sysdate)` truncate the date to day; 2011-04-19 23:32:34 becomes 2011-04-19 00:00:00, i.e. removing the time component. 
`next_day(sysdate, 'SUN')` returns the next sunday. If sysdate happens to be a sunday, the next sunday is returned.
**Important**: The day names have to be in the same language as your session.
The `interval` thing is just a standard way of adding/subtracting different units of time from a date.

Putting it all together, the logic for the 19th of April 2011 would be:

1. Truncate sysdate => 2011-04-19 00:00:00
2. subtract 14 days => 2011-04-05 00:00:00
3. Find the next sunday => 2011-04-10 00:00:00

...and

1. Truncate sysdate => 2011-04-19 00:00:00
2. subtract 7 days => 2011-04-12 00:00:00
3. Find the next sunday => 2011-04-17 00:00:00

..resulting in the following query:

```
 where resolved_date >= timestamp '2011-04-10 00:00:00'
   and resolved_date <  timestamp '2011-04-17 00:00:00'
```

All resolved_dates that happened on or after the first second of the 10:th but before the first second of the 17:th would be included. Note that `>=` and `<` isn't equivalent to `between`.

A note on performance: I would make sure that Oracle correctly estimates the date range to be 7 days, and that the correct join order/method is used. If you expect the query to run for a while, you can afford to calculate the dates in the application and supply them as date litterals instead of computing them on the fly like I did above.

Comment: I accepted this, even though it didn't quite work in my environment, because it led me to the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the to_date function:  http://psoug.org/reference/builtin_functions.html