# Using System Date to Acquire Mon - Fri

Tags: sql, oracle

How do you acquire the current business week on any given day during the week using sysdate?  I would like have one sql statement that gives me activity for the current week that we are operating in without having to have 5 different sql statements.  Is this possible?

Comment: Almost certainly, yes. However, I'm not really certain what you're asking because the answer to the question _"How do you acquire the current business week on any given day during the week using System Date?"_ is the last three words in that question; by using the system date, `sysdate`. Could you be _a lot_ more specific about what you're attempting to do; include data and possible queries as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  SYSDATE
FROM    DUAL
;
-- 2013-11-04 11:06:14

SELECT  TRUNC(SYSDATE+3) - (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE+3, 'D') - 1)
,       TRUNC(SYSDATE+3) - (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE+3, 'D') - 5)
FROM    DUAL
;
-- 2013-11-04 00:00:00  2013-11-08 00:00:00


SELECT  TRUNC(SYSDATE+2) - (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE+2, 'D') - 1)
,       TRUNC(SYSDATE+2) - (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE+2, 'D') - 5)
FROM    DUAL
;
-- 2013-11-04 00:00:00  2013-11-08 00:00:00


SELECT  TRUNC(SYSDATE+1) - (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE+1, 'D') - 1)
,       TRUNC(SYSDATE+1) - (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE+1, 'D') - 5)
FROM    DUAL
;
-- 2013-11-04 00:00:00  2013-11-08 00:00:00


SELECT  TRUNC(SYSDATE) - (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'D') - 1)
,       TRUNC(SYSDATE) - (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'D') - 5)
FROM    DUAL
;
-- 2013-11-04 00:00:00  2013-11-08 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to use the [next_day()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions098.htm) function to achieve this. You will have to try out a few combinations of this function to do it in 1 SQL Statement.

Here's some pseudo-code. I haven't tested this, but it should be enough to get you started.

```
where my_operating_date >= next_day( trunc(sysdate) - interval '7' day, 'MON')
and my_operating_date <  next_day( trunc(sysdate) - interval '2'  day, 'FRI')
```

I modified the pseduo-code from [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5722412/325521) that addresses a similar requirement for getting previous week. The explanation on that answer should get you going. Be sure to test heavily for edge cases, like if current day is Mon or Fri.